# bash while loop not terminating

Tags: bash

I wrote this one liner in bash:

```
while read line; printf $line' '; do : ; done < someFile
```

and it seemed to go over the lines of the files fine, but then it went into an infinite loop typing spaces. I realized my mistake was putting the `printf` before the `do` instead of after, but I still don't understand what's going on in here. Why do I get an infinite loop?

Comment: Do not `printf $line' '` which will most likely fail if the value of `line` starts with a dash (this is BTW a way to unintentionally break your infinite loop). Do `printf '%s ' "$line"` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've misplaced `do`.  You want:

```
while read line; do printf "%s" "$line "; done < someFile
```

The way you've written it is valid, but the semantics are not what you expect.

```
while read line; printf $line' '; do : ; done < someFile
```

is reading the line and then printing it.  The value returned by printf is evaluated to determine if the loop body is entered.  Since printf succeeds, it enters the loop.

The general syntax is `while {list of commands}; do {list of commands}; done`  The first list of commands is executed, and the result of the final command is evaluated to determine if the loop body is entered.

But it seems what you really want is:

```
tr \\n ' ' < someFile
```

Comment: I know I misplaced the `do`, it's written in the question, but the explanation is helpful. Also the `:` is just a place holder here, I did other stuff with `line` in there

Answer (score 0):

the correct syntax is

```
while read line; do printf $line' '; done  < someFile
```

try it ;)

if write in multi-line script if better to understand

```
#!/bin/bash   
while read line
do
  printf $line' '
done < SomeFile
```

Comment: you're right i saw the do error and i didn't read right after

Usali I add IFS= option before read command to prevent leading/trailing whitespace from being trimmed -

`code` while IFS= read -r line; do COMMAND_on $line; done `code`